# Unable to create SKSpriteNode in playground using imageNamed initializer in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, xcode6.1, skspritenode, swift-playground

I am getting an `Unknown error` thrown by the compiler or runtime in Swift when trying to create a SKSpriteNode as follows in the playground file.

`let healthSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "health")`

[image: Unknown error]

I have health.png placed inside Resources folder inside the playground file as seen here https://github.com/jocelynlih/SwiftGameBook/tree/master/Playgrounds/Life%20Line%20Node.playground/Resources

Is this a known issue and does someone know how to solve this. I am able to create a UIImage using `UIImage(named: "health")` but if I make an `SKTexture` using the image I get the same `Unknown error`

Comment: do you get an actual error? can you post the full error message?

Comment: There is no full error stack. It just shows `Unknown error` when I open the console also.